android-based ordering app java firebase: can't fetch data of seller in user dashboard
I have two userType (user and seller).The issue is that i can't fetch the data of seller in user recycleview or in any textview.
Example:  in recycleview i have cardview and it contains textview (sellerName) and i want the (sellerName) change text to the literal name of the seller but but it become "null" or sometimes it will become empty textview. please help me i think there is something wrong in my Adapter or model.
i try to overrides the textview using in cardview
holder.sellerNameTV.setText(sellername)
but the Result: "null" or sometimes empty
MODELSHOP
package com.example.orenglo.model;

public class ModelShop {

    String id,name, shopName, password, timestamp, uid,address, userType, email,  profileImage;

    Boolean onlinestatus, shopOpen;

    public ModelShop() {
    }

    public ModelShop(String id, String name, String shopName, String password, String timestamp, String uid, String address, String userType, String email, String profileImage, Boolean onlinestatus, Boolean shopOpen) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.shopName = shopName;
        this.password = password;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.uid = uid;
        this.address = address;
        this.userType = userType;
        this.email = email;
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
        this.onlinestatus = onlinestatus;
        this.shopOpen = shopOpen;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getShopName() {
        return shopName;
    }

    public void setShopName(String shopName) {
        this.shopName = shopName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(String timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return userType;
    }

    public void setUserType(String userType) {
        this.userType = userType;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    public Boolean getOnlinestatus() {
        return onlinestatus;
    }

    public void setOnlinestatus(Boolean onlinestatus) {
        this.onlinestatus = onlinestatus;
    }

    public Boolean getShopOpen() {
        return shopOpen;
    }

    public void setShopOpen(Boolean shopOpen) {
        this.shopOpen = shopOpen;
    }
}

ADAPTERSHOP
public class AdapterShop extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterShop.HolderShop> {

private Context context;

public ArrayList<ModelShop> shopsList;

public AdapterShop(Context context, ArrayList<ModelShop> shopsList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.shopsList = shopsList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public HolderShop onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_shop,parent,false);
    return new HolderShop(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HolderShop holder, int position) {

    ModelShop modelShop = shopsList.get(position);
    String name = modelShop.getName();
    String shopName = modelShop.getShopName();
    String password = modelShop.getPassword();
    String timestamp = modelShop.getTimestamp();
    String uid = modelShop.getUid();
    String shopId = modelShop.getId();
    String address = modelShop.getAddress();
    String userType = modelShop.getUserType();
    String email = modelShop.getEmail();
    Boolean onlinestatus = modelShop.getOnlinestatus();
    Boolean shopOpen = modelShop.getShopOpen();
    String profileImage = modelShop.getProfileImage();

    holder.shopNameTV.setText(shopName);
    holder.addresstv.setText(address);

    try {
            Picasso.get().load(profileImage).placeholder(R.drawable.orenglotwo).into(holder.shopIconIV);
        }catch (Exception e){
            holder.shopIconIV.setImageResource(R.drawable.orenglotwo);
        }


    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ShopdetailsActivity.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return shopsList.size();
}

class HolderShop extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {



    private ImageView shopIconIV, onlineStatsIV;

    private TextView shopNameTV, addresstv, phonenumTV, shopClosedTV;


    public HolderShop(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        shopClosedTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopClosedtxt);
        shopIconIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopiconIV);
        onlineStatsIV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.onlineStatsIV);
        shopNameTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.shopnametextview);
        addresstv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.addresstextview);
        phonenumTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.phonenumtextview);

    }
}

}
ROWSHOP LAYOUT ID
     android:id="@+id/shopnametextview"
     android:id="@+id/addresstextview"

FIREBASE
"Users": {
"239wDmHPnlN0EeUxONltkYYax6q1": {
  "address": "North",
  "contactnumber": "09491026737",
  "email": "orenglocentral@gmail.com",
  "name": "orenglo",
  "online": "true",
  "onlinestatus": "true",
  "profileImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/orenglo.appspot.com/o/profile_images%2F239wDmHPnlN0EeUxONltkYYax6q1?alt=media&token=e8a90c5b-9793-4a66-a9f2-f85f568f6930",
  "shopName": "OrengloCentral",
  "shopOpen": true,
  "timestamp": "4/13/24 9:44 PM",
  "uid": "239wDmHPnlN0EeUxONltkYYax6q1",
  "userType": "admin"
}

Hashmap
 HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>(); hashMap.put("name",name); hashMap.put("shopName",shopname); hashMap.put("password",password); hashMap.put("timestamp",timestamp); hashMap.put("uid",uid); hashMap.put("contactnumber", contact); hashMap.put("address", address); hashMap.put("userType","admin"); hashMap.put("email",email); hashMap.put("onlinestatus","true"); hashMap.put("profileImage", "");


Can you please share some Code?

show the code where in you bind the data to your view and show the data that is coming from the firebase

@RenzSalanga I post the codes above, please take a look what is the problem thankyou so much! i've been stuck for 2days finding whatsthe prob.

@Cristi post the codes above, please take a look what is the problem thankyou so much! i've been stuck for 2days finding whatsthe prob.

@BaldivicioBrian add the code where in you map the firebase response to the ModelShop class. Basically where you create an instance of ModelShop

@Bribloomgg: please don't post significant updates in comments. Instead: edit your question (there's a small edit link under it for that purpose) and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to make it readable.

@FrankvanPuffelen Noted, My apologies.

Did MUHAMMAD ALDIAN NUR's answer solve the problem?
